# Link Types for Plugins

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I'm new to Banno so I apologize if this is common knowledge but I couldn't find anything in the Banno knowledge base. I've looked at link types (https://knowledge.banno.com/apps/partnerintegrations/linktypes) that you over for plugins but couldn't find the one I was looking for. There are blue links above the Banno cards in the dashboard and I'm wondering if I have access to these links. I would like to create a link there for my application. Below is a screenshot of the links I'm talking about.

[image: Banno Links]

From what I understand, I have the ability to add my link there but only in the account details page. I would like to add my link to the dashboard page above the section containing the Banno Plugin Cards. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% certain about that specific location (on the Dashboard above the area where cards, both built-in and plugins, reside). Will check with Product & Engineering teams for clarity. Thank you very much for linking our doc...that helps narrow things down for us!

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Let me know what they say.

Comment: Following up: the area that you're interested in configuring is _not_ configurable by developers.